# Variable breaking scope

Tags: c#

How come this gives a `'s' does not exist in the current context` error (as expected):

```
public static void Main()
{
    foreach(var i in new[]{1, 2, 3}) {
        int s = i;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

([ideone](https://ideone.com/pe1r56))

But this gives a `'s' cannot be redeclared` error?

```
public static void Main()
{
    foreach(var i in new[]{1, 2, 3}) {
        int s = i;
    }

    int s = 4;
}
```

([ideone](https://ideone.com/Dwn7CO))

The first error tells me that `s` doesn't exist outside of the `foreach`, which makes sense, but the second error says otherwise.  Why (and how!?) would I ever need to access a variable from a child scope?

Comment: Because you try to re-declared `s` in second one? Isn't that normal?

Comment: The compiler tries to protect you from careless mistakes. That's why you cannot declare a variable which was already declared in the same method, even if that variable is not accessible.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: There is no lexical scoping in a method body.

Comment: Yes, but the code should be still valid/correct the way it is.  That compiler error is something I'd expect from a Linter.

Comment: @Jaxo: you should ask yourself: why do i need the same variable name behind the `foreach` that i have used in the `foreach`? What do you gain from it? Imho nothing but a great source of errors because you are confusing them. If you later want to move it to the top of the method it wouldn't compile anyway. I like that the compiler sometimes points me in the right direction to write better code(in terms of robustness, maintainability and readability).

Comment: The reason I ran into this error is because I was updating several database records within the `foreach`, which is why I had declared a `var entry`.  After the foreach, I run a final update on a different record.  The tables are normalized and as small as I can get them, I should really just be using more descriptive variable names than `var entry = db.Entry(theObject)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> The first error tells me that s doesn't exist outside of the foreach, which makes sense

Indeed - it's right.

> but the second error says otherwise.

No, it doesn't. It's telling you that you can't declare the *first* (nested) variable `s`, because the *second* one is already in scope. You can't access it before the declaration, but it's in *scope* for the whole block.

From the C# 5 specification, section 3.7:

> • The scope of a local variable declared in a local-variable-declaration (§8.5.1) is the block in which the declaration occurs.

So yes, it extends upwards to the enclosing `{`., basically.

And then from section 8.5.1:

> The scope of a local variable declared in a local-variable-declaration is the block in which the declaration occurs. It is an error to refer to a local variable in a textual position that precedes the local-variable-declarator of the local variable. **Within the scope of a local variable, it is a compile-time error to declare another local variable or constant with the same name.**

That final part (emphasis mine) is why you're getting an error.

> Why (and how!?) would I ever need to access a variable from a child scope?

Not sure what you mean here, but the rule is basically there to make it harder for you to write hard-to-read or fragile code. It means there are fewer places where moving the declaration of the variable up or down (but still in the same block, at the same level of nesting) produces code which is valid but with a different meaning.

Comment: Hey Jon, I was about to post along these lines and provide further clarification however, since you are here and might save me a few minutes of confirmation by looking at some ILASM, does this occur because the C# compiler moves variable declarations to the top of each method?  It's been a long time since I looked into this, but I seem that being the reason why this is a problem.  Am I off base?

Comment: @RLH: I don't know IL in detail, but I don't believe there's any notion of a variable declaration within a method of IL - there's just something which says what local variables there are. It's not like there are separate IL statements of "Declare this variable, then declare that variable" as far as I'm aware.

Comment: I see, I was hoping it wasn't the case where variables would be hoisted up to method level.  Thank you!

Comment: @Jaxo: What difference would you expect it to make? Ignore the IL - that's an implementation detail. Just focus on the *language* rules.

Comment: Hey Jon, I agree with the "pay attention to the language rules"... rule, but if someone is curious about the *why* then they might be asking, what does this rule exist in the first place.  I'm going to post a secondary answer, outlining what's going on behind the scenes.  Since I'm not an engineer at MS, I can only speculate why this is taking place.  Stay tuned.

Comment: @RLH: The "why" is entirely separate from IL. The language could have been designed to allow this and still generate appropriate IL. The reason the language has been designed like this is to make it harder to shoot yourself in the foot - not due to IL limitations.

Comment: Absolutely - but this is the kind of thing I'd expect to see in a warning at most - not completely halt the compiler because it doesn't like my variable names.

Comment: @Jaxo: I'll see whether there's anything in the annotated spec, but basically it *is* because the code could be so confusing otherwise. (I'm confident I've seen that written somewhere, but I can't remember the source right now. It's likely to either be the annotated spec or an Eric Lippert blog post.) Personally I'm entirely happy with it being a compile-time error. It's only to do with *local* variables, so it's not like other code can break your code without you doing anything (unlike a base class introducing another member, for example, resulting in a warning saying you should use "new").

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first consider the following, simple class implementation.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TestNamespace
{
    class ILOrderTest
    {
        public int DeclarationTests()
        {
            int intDeclaredAtTop = 0;

            for (int intDeclaredInForLoopDef = 0; intDeclaredInForLoopDef < 10; intDeclaredInForLoopDef++)
            {
                int intDeclaredInForLoopBody = intDeclaredInForLoopDef;
                intDeclaredAtTop = intDeclaredInForLoopBody;
            }
            int intDeclaredAfterForLoop;
            intDeclaredAfterForLoop = intDeclaredAtTop;
            return intDeclaredAfterForLoop;
        }
    }
}
```

As we can see, many variables are declared at different locations of our method and it could be assumed that when the C# interpreter reads our file, it will organize the IL in such a way that declared objects will be defined where we wrote our variable definition code.

However, after compiling and inspecting our IL we see a much different story.

**Class ILOrderTest IL**

```
.method public hidebysig 
    instance int32 DeclarationTests () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 38 (0x26)
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] int32 intDeclaredAtTop,
        [1] int32 intDeclaredInForLoopDef,
        [2] int32 intDeclaredInForLoopBody,
        [3] int32 intDeclaredAfterForLoop,
        [4] int32 CS$1$0000,
        [5] bool CS$4$0001
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldc.i4.0
    IL_0002: stloc.0
    IL_0003: ldc.i4.0
    IL_0004: stloc.1
    IL_0005: br.s IL_0011
    // loop start (head: IL_0011)
        IL_0007: nop
        IL_0008: ldloc.1
        IL_0009: stloc.2
        IL_000a: ldloc.2
        IL_000b: stloc.0
        IL_000c: nop
        IL_000d: ldloc.1
        IL_000e: ldc.i4.1
        IL_000f: add
        IL_0010: stloc.1

        IL_0011: ldloc.1
        IL_0012: ldc.i4.s 10
        IL_0014: clt
        IL_0016: stloc.s CS$4$0001
        IL_0018: ldloc.s CS$4$0001
        IL_001a: brtrue.s IL_0007
    // end loop

    IL_001c: ldloc.0
    IL_001d: stloc.3
    IL_001e: ldloc.3
    IL_001f: stloc.s CS$1$0000
    IL_0021: br.s IL_0023

    IL_0023: ldloc.s CS$1$0000
    IL_0025: ret
} // end of method ILOrderTest::DeclarationTests
```

Notice that all of our objects for our method have been gathered together and initialized in the `.locals init...` call at the top of our method.  If I find the time, I may do a little further digging on *why* the .Net IL is organized this way, but if I had to make an educated guess it would be that variable declaration has a certain level of overhead involved and that bundling together all variables within a particular scope might save a few CPU cycles, instead of making many calls to `.locals init...` , every time that a new object is declared.

I hope that provides a little further clarity.  Jons answer is correct by spec definition, but this could shed a little light on why the spec was written that way.

Comment: Wow!  You're probably right about the compiler trying to optimize so aggressively, which would break when it tries to put two variables with the same signature in the same place.  Great explanation, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you like to have two distinct variables with name `s` you can do something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    foreach(var i in new[]{1, 2, 3}) {
        int s = i;
    }

    // better describe what you do in this scope
    // (and let others know that this is not just an ordinary if-clause)
    {
        int s = 4;
    }
}
```

But in most cases you will need to declare `s` outside the scope and initialize with a default value:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    int s = default(int);
    foreach(var i in new[] { 1, 2, 3 }) {
        s = i;
        //use s in loop
    }
    //use s after loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C# is like Java in this respect: it doesn't allow you to declare a variable with the same name in a different level of scope, even if the first instance of the variable is out of scope.

You *can* do this in C and C++.

I think this is down to a school of thought that suggests that code can become unintelligible / unstable if such behaviour is permitted.

Comment: Isn't that called shadowing?

Comment: I definitely agree with the compiler trying to help out with code readability.  I do a lot of Javascript, and this kind of thing [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/zv8bjagf/1/).